# HOw Do I update from table-2 to table-1

Tags: php, mysql

HI what is the wrong in this code?? i have set it 24 hours to update the value in the table.but the problem is if $row is empty then it inserts value from table-2 but after 24 hours it wont update the value.

what I want is it must delete the existing value and insert new one(random value) or it must update the same $row with new value what ever...

```
if ($row == 0){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO table-1 
  (regtime,person,location,address,rank,ip,geocode)
  SELECT NOW(),person,location,address,rank,ip,geocode FROM table-2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
}
else{
  mysql_query("UPDATE table-1 SELECT regtime=NOW(),
                 person=person,
                 location=location,
                 address=address,
                 rank=rank,
                 ip=ip,
                 geocode=geocode FROM table-2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to DELETE the existing rows in table-1 before running the INSERT.

I don't know what the primary key of your table is. I suppose its person?

```
DELETE FROM table-1 where person in (select person FROM table-2)

INSERT INTO table-1 (regtime,person,location,address,rank,ip,geocode) 
SELECT NOW(),person,location,address,rank,ip,geocode FROM table-2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Sorry If I got something wrong, I am not using mysql.

Comment: NOP primary key is id and only one row is there so say id = 1

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO

Answer (score 0):

There is no `SET` in your `UPDATE` statement, that's why is not doing anything.

See the [`UPDATE` manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: can you tell me where to add that SET ?? I have added according to my knowledge and then removed.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET columnname = value WHERE condition`